# Safest place to store data

Tags: data, storage

What is safest possible way to store data? Specific directory? (De-)hashing method? Specific permissions?

Let say I have file `*.txt` file; the only `*.txt` file. I have there important data. What can I do with this file to make it as safe as possible for further use. For Windows Vista and newer (7/8/Blue).
I could use it to see if game is really bought, not cracked etc. .

Comment: There is no such thing as "secure storage" on a client.

Comment: I haven't said "secure" I said "most secure possible". To be specific, I said "safest way possible" not "safe way".

Comment: I think the intent is similar to this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/minimizing-chances-of-piracy/23638

Comment: I'd say this question is either too broad, or off topic. Game developers are not file security experts. Further, if there was a "safest" place on the file system, I would hope that a program downloaded from the internet (your game) wouldn't be able to access it, making it not very safe at all. That means your program is left to access only the areas where any other application can access. That's as safe as it gets.

Comment: Just throw it into one of the Appdata folders.

Comment: Probably related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/how-can-i-protect-my-save-data-from-casual-hacking

Comment: Safest from who? The user (who owns and controls the machine)? Other programs? Monsters from under the bed...?

Answer (score 1):

Really, the safest way to store data is on a remote server.  By safe, I mean, no one can really touch the data except for the ways you allow the data to be accessed.

A good question to ask yourself is, is my data worth protecting?

If this game was a simple single player game with no contact with the outside world (eg. online high scores, online multiplayer), why bother protecting that data?

If the game is online in some way, then don't bother storing sensative data locally.

**If your goal is to prevent people stealing your game, then have it look online for validation and store keys and IP Addresses on your servers**.  That way you can see *who* is using your game.  If this is done, be aware that ISP's sometimes hand out random IP's in their massive pools of IP addresses.