# Simple Anti-piracy techniques

Tags: piracy

I'm releasing a game soon and thinking about adding some simple anti-piracy techniques.

It's an offline adventure game but I'm thinking of doing a quick background check on startup for updates if the user is connected online.

Since it'd connect to the game site to check this, maybe there's some anti-piracy check I can do at the same time?

I don't want anything that'd annoy the user, and I'm not too bothered about completely removing the ability to pirate it because that'd be fighting a losing battle. I just want something that'd deter casual pirates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. In general, anything you do as anti-piracy, can be undone by hackers. The only question is "how hard is it" or how much of a deterrent it is.

Comment: [This question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/minimizing-chances-of-piracy) is a possible duplicate.